# Refactor namespaces in a library while keeping backwards-compatibility

Tags: c#, api, refactoring, libraries, namespace

We developed a generic .NET library for our line-of business applications. This is what our namespace/class structure looked like 5 years ago:

```
...
AcmeCorp.Tools.ExcelWriter
AcmeCorp.Tools.Code128Barcode
...
```

5 years later, the number of classes in the generic `Tools` namespace has grown (e.g. there's now a `CSVWriter` in addition to an `ExcelWriter` and a `QRBarcode` in addition to a `Code128Barcode`). Thus, I'd like to refactor the namespaces to look like this:

```
...
AcmeCorp.Export.ExcelWriter
AcmeCorp.Export.CSVWriter
AcmeCorp.Export.SomeUtilityClassUsedByAllExportClasses
AcmeCorp.Barcode.Code128Barcode
AcmeCorp.Barcode.QRBarcode
...
```

I [know how to refactor namespaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4809197/87698) - that's not the question. The question is: **How do I keep my library backwards-compatible?**

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
namespace AcmeCorp.Barcode
{
    [AlsoAvailableViaDeprecatedLegacyNamespace("AcmeCorp.Tools")]
    public class Code128Barcode
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

which would automatically create a proxy class `AcmeCorp.Tools.Code128Barcode` which (a) redirects all calls to the new class and (b) annotates the proxy class with the `[Obsolete("Use AcmeCorp.Barcode.Code128Barcode instead.")]` attribute. Alas, no such `AlsoAvailableViaDeprecatedLegacyNamespace` attribute exists. (Or does it?)

The only other solution I could think of would be to write such a proxy class myself, which would be a *lot* of useless boilerplate code.

Is there any other solution that I have missed? To reiterate: My goal is to

- move classes into a more suitable namespaces, but
- keep the library backwards-compatible (no [source-level or binary-level breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456785/87698)),
- avoid code duplication and boilerplate code (as far as possible), and
- (bonus:) mark all uses of the "old" namespace as obsolete.

Comment: You might be interested in the [TypeForwardedTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553463/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-typeforwardedtoattribute) attribute.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I keep my library backwards-compatible?

The short answer is: you can't.

If you move a type from one namespace to another, your choices are to manually create a delegation class in the old place that internally maps to the new location (and mark it obsolete), or you make a breaking change.

But I'd question what you are proposing anyway. There exists the design warning, [*CA1020: Avoid namespaces with few types*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1020-avoid-namespaces-with-few-types?view=vs-2015). It exists because Microsoft's guidelines state:

> *Make sure that each of your namespaces has a logical organization, and that a valid reason exists to put types in a sparsely populated namespace. Namespaces should contain types that are used together in most scenarios. When their applications are mutually exclusive, types should be located in separate namespaces*

In other words, "*the number of classes in the generic Tools namespace has grown*" is not necessarily a good reason to move types out of a namespace.

**UPDATE**

Ewan shows a practical way of achieving "*manually create a delegation class in the old place that internally maps to the new location (and mark it obsolete)*". There's one point to note here in relation to your question though. Every developer worth their salt will set the "treat warnings as errors" flag on their code. Those `Obsolete` attributes will result in warnings, which in turn result in errors. So this approach is still technically a breaking change.

Don't be shy of breaking changes though. That's what semantic versioning is there for.

Comment: You raise some very valuable points, thanks. I'm less scared about `Obsolete` being a breaking change, because that use case is *exactly* what the `Obsolete` attribute is made for. If developers want to treat obsolete warnings as errors, that's their choice (and it's usually a good choice, just saying), but it shouldn't stop a library developer from using the Obsolete attribute as it has been intended.

Comment: *"Don't be shy of breaking changes though. That's what semantic versioning is there for."* In theory, yes. In practice, going from v1.x.x to v2.0.0 means that, for a considerable amount of time, I'll have to maintain *two* branches of my library, since not everyone sees incorporating my breaking changes as their top priority.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bad idea, just make a new version with the new namespace. But....

```
namespace oldNameSpace
{
    [Obsolete("use the new namespace")]
    public class origionalClass
    {
    }
}

namespace newNameSpace
{
    public class origonalClass: oldNameSpace.origonalClass
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: For many, that will work well. In my view though, it's good practice to mark all API classes as `sealed`, so this approach doesn't work. It becomes necessary to write a delegation class instead. More work, but equally achievable.

Comment: Nice idea. Yes, it's a hack (abusing inheritance for code reuse), but, so far, it comes closest to what I had in mind. I'd probably reverse the inheritance, though, i.e., I'd move the class into the new namespace and have the old class inherit from the new one. This has a few advantages: (1) The actual code is in the new namespace, where it should be, (2) removing the old class won't require changes in the new class, (3) the ugly additional "compatibility layer" in the inheritance hierarchy is only in the ugly old class, which we don't want to use anymore anyway, not in the shiny new class.

Comment: The drawback of my approach (old inherits from new) would be that the new class can't be sealed (as David Arno correctly mentions in his comment), but that's something I can live with.

Comment: as you are changing the code you can simply unseal the old class as required. Of course then someone might inherit from it, but you have marked it obsolete and are removing it anyway